# I tried to do sudo apt-get update and it asked me to write my password but i cant write it why? Someone plz help me

Tags: password

Why I can’t type my password when I type `sudo apt-get update`?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Please refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic, Ubuntu and official *flavors* of Ubuntu (https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours) are on-topic on this site. We are sorry, Kali-Linux is off-topic. You can use https://forums.kali.org/ but Kali-Linux is intended for experienced GNU/Linux users and users are expected to fix their own problems, and only when that fails to have them ask a question with a well-documented problem.    (see the on-topic link for the alternate SE *Unix & Linux* site).

Answer (score 2):

When typing your password using the terminal no text will appear. You are, however, still entering the password. Type it and hit enter - nothing will happen on the screen until you hit enter. If you typed it correctly, the process will continue and if incorrect you will get an error message.